# Weird Question: VSCode marked text surrounded with character

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know, its a weird question, but is there a way to make the selected text surrounded by two charakters like in 4coder?

e.g. ⌊Selected Text⌉

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a snippet on a key binding:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+k 1", // or some other combo
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "[${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}]$0"
  }
}
```